# confidence interval shading disappears in certain programs when saved as pdf

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I am using ggplot (Version 3.2.5) for a line graph with geom_line. For my confidence interval I use geom_smooth. I then save the plot with

> ggsave("Name.pdf", width=8, height=6, dpi=300)

I run OS X El Capitan and Word 2016. If I copy this graph into Word 2016 on my Mac the grey shading of the cofidence interval can be seen.

The problem is when I open the same graph on Windows in Word or Powerpoint the grey shading disappears.

Any suggestions what the problem could be are highly appreciated. I always thought that a .pdf is something that should look the same no matter what programm gets used.

Comment: Try using CairoPDF or other PDF devices than the one `ggsave` uses. I'm dealing with serious PDF output consistencies on macOS as well.